# Change column number in a set range

Tags: excel, vba

I've set rng as range.
Currently, rng has the following value:

```
$M$5:$M$7,$M$13:$M$15,$M$17:$M$19,$M$22:$M$23,$M$25:$M$26
```

I'd like to reassign the column number in this range.
For example:

```
rng.Column = 1 'or
set rng.Column = 1 'or
rng.Column = "A"
```

Anyone know how I can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Intersect:

```
Set rng = Intersect(rng.EntireRow,rng.Parent.Range("A:A"))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to change the range-column from **M** to **A**, then try something like:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Range("$M$5:$M$7,$M$13:$M$15,$M$17:$M$19,$M$22:$M$23,$M$25:$M$26")
    Set rng = Range(Replace(rng.Address, "M", "A"))
    MsgBox rng.Address
End Sub
```

[image]